# Windows 7 & gVim makeprg/shellpipe setup to show build output

Tags: vim

I'm trying to setup vim on windows to work like it does in Linux. Basically, when I type ":make" in linux, I get the output of makeprg sort of streaming through vim itself.

On windows I get a cmd prompt that comes up, but behind vim. I have to switch focus to view the results until they are finished and then they can be viewed in the quickfix window.

I attempted to download a copy of "tee" and set shellpipe to |tee, but that didn't really change anything. Below are the sort of relevant settings in my vimrc, I use ninja, but the same happens if I switch to nmake or something similar.

```
set makeprg=ninja\ -C\ build-ninja
set shellpipe=2>&1\ \|tee
set efm+=%Dninja:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',%Xninja:\ leaving\ directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886722/vim-autocmd-silent-execution) is related to what you want, but provides only for a partial solution, because it will not wait until the program has finished running:

> set makeprg=start\ /min\ ninja\ -C\ build-ninja

Getting it to work will not be trivial (see comments), it seems like an important oversight of the Windows version of Vim, because start cannot be executed from makeprg (see comments), only the internal (and more limited !start).

The full documentation of the start program (which it seems you would need to somehow invoke) you can find [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/31608/can-i-run-a-gui-program-in-the-background-on-the-windows-command-line/31621#31621)

Comment: It is not going to work: a) there is no “!start” program, only “start” b) you forgot to escape spaces c) “start” treats `/wait` as a start of the command because it is not `start` program. `!start` is handled by vim internally and accepts only `/min` and `/b` arguments, only one of them at a time.

Comment: To use `start` program you have to escape it using double quotes. And escape quotes for use in `:set`. As I don’t like all those escapes command should look like `let &makeprg='"start" /min /wait ninja -C build-ninja'`, but it doesn’t look like it actually works: in this case “command not found errors” are not thrown which are if I use your variant with a) and b) issues resolved (i.e. removed bang and escaped spaces), but nothing gets started as well. It looks like cmd.exe just don’t like quotes here. Alternative is space before `start`, but leading spaces are stripped of `&makeprg` when run.

Comment: You can, of course, escape spaces and remove bang. It won’t make built-in replacement of `start` accept `/wait` argument. And `&makeprg` is unfortunately passed directly to the same code that is responsible for handling `!` commands with leading spaces stripped. I know how to resolve this issue (supply absolute path to executable), but `start.exe` is *not* capturing started programs output (at least its wine implementation). Hence it is useless as `&makeprg` value.

Comment: Yeah, I got stuck with the same situation as you posted in your third comment. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @ZyX I've edited the answer to reflect that following this approach a full solution will not be very straightforward, given what internally Vim seems to be doing.

Comment: It *can* be executed as I said in the third comment: supply full path to `start.exe` in place of just `start`. But when you redirect output from that program you will find out that file contents differs very much from what you expected: it is empty, start.exe is not capturing command output. Thus not vim builtin is a problem, but start.exe itself.

Comment: It may be different on windows though. But I believe wine authors were careful in start.exe reimplementation and have not missed such obvious thing.

Comment: @ZyX: I don't think there is start.exe program (or at least not one that i could find quickly in my Win7 laptop), it is more of cmd builtin, like echo or alias in bash.

Comment: I am testing on wine in 32-bit Windows XP emulation mode. It does have start program: in `C:/windows/command/start.exe` and `C:/windows/system32/start.exe`, they are different ones (diff reports they differ, but I do not know how exactly) and they accept `/wait` option which does exactly what you wanted: wait until program finishes (by the way, without `/wait` option it is completely useless as `&makeprg`. Though it is already completely useless due to absence of redirection so…). If `start` is only a builtin in Windows 7 you can still call it using `cmd.exe /s /c "start …`, but redirection …

Comment: For what it's worth, `let &makeprg='"start" /min /wait ninja -C build-ninja'` gives the exact behavior that gVim was giving me already. Basically, I get the results in a new cmd window when they should be in gVim as they happen. Removing /min makes it pop up in a cmd window which does seem like an improvement. Ideally shellpipe would actually just work.

Comment: I'll accept this one as I think shellpipe is just not going to work with windows correctly.